# Why isn't this SQL statement to check if a table exists valid?

Tags: mysql, sql

```
IF object_id('player_data', 'U') IS NOT NULL
  SELECT 'player_data exists' AS ''
ELSE
  SELECT 'player_data does not exist' AS ''
```

I have a database named versusarenadata that, once set up, will contain a table named player_data as well as others. I need to check at startup if the database has been configured, so I'm trying to use this block of code, which is obviously for testing only, to check whether I can proceed with reading data or I need to do initial setup. Why am I getting an error message saying:

> "#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax"?

Comment: Why don't you simply use `SHOW TABLES;` to check what tables exist?

Comment: `object_id` is a function in SQL Server.  I don't think MySQL has the same function, but I could be mistaken.

Comment: @arkascha, how would I go about checking the existence of a specific table using that command?

Comment: I just started learning SQL yesterday, so I haven't figured out the syntax very well.

Comment: I suggest you start reading the excellent mysql documentation. This clearly states that you can use operators for this: `SHOW TABLES LIKE '%player_data%';`...

Answer (score 1):

You can query [`information_schema.tables`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/tables-table.html) to see if a table with that name exists in your current database like so:

```
select (case 
  when count(*) = 0 
  then 'player_data does not exist' 
  else 'player_data exists' 
  end)         
from information_schema.tables 
where table_schema = database()
and table_name = 'player_data';
```

Alternatively you could just try to create the table using [`create table if not exists`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/create-table.html), which will do nothing if the table already exists:

```
create table if not exists player_data
...
```

Comment: What is the significance of the database function? Does it return the database from which the query is called?

Comment: Yes, it returns the name of the current database (schema) for your session. I added that to the query because there could be tables named "player_data" in other schemas that you don't want to count.

Comment: Cool. I got that to work by changing database() to the literal name of my database because for some reason database() was returning "information_schema".

Answer (score 0):

I don't think `PRINT` is a sql keyword. If you want to print a string in your results you need to make it a query like this:

```
SELECT 'player data exists' as ''
```

Comment: Hmm, I saw it used somewhere in an example. I guess I was mistaken.